# TextBox with comma into sql

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to insert a textbox with a decimal value into sql.
If the textbox will contain dot then it works fine, but what if someone will use comma instead of dot? How can i catch both situations?

Example i want to insert value 1,9

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into inventory (price) values ('" + Convert.ToDecimal(textBox1.Text) + "')", con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

I'm taking Error converting data type varchar to float.
I need whatever user will put in textbox, dot or comma to convert it as float value into sql

Comment: Parametrise your SQL, please! Also, rather than using`float` I strongly recommend `decimal`. `float` is an inaccurate data type, and so has problems like rounding issues. In terms of the text box, why not set validation to stop characters other than numbers and a decimal point.

Comment: Well first off your code is extremely vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You need to use parameterized queries

Comment: Second. Use [Decimal.TryParse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx) with the correct culture info

Comment: Dmitry is replace the right method? I mean , what in case that i will run this into another computer with other globalization settings? Is right this method for all countries globalization settings? maccettura Should i send also datadype of column for this?

Comment: Replace won't help if you someone enters the text: `1'); DROP TABLE inventory;--`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know whether the user will use a comma or period as the decimal separator (unaware of their culture), you could try both. Below is a parameterized example.

```
    decimal decimalValue;

    NumberFormatInfo formatWithPeriod = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat;
    if (!Decimal.TryParse(textBox.Text, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, formatWithPeriod, out decimalValue))
    {
        NumberFormatInfo formatWithComma = (NumberFormatInfo)formatWithPeriod.Clone();
        formatWithComma.NumberDecimalSeparator = ",";
        if (!Decimal.TryParse(textBox.Text, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, formatWithComma, out decimalValue))
        {
            //error here
            return;
        }
    }

    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into inventory (price) values (@price);", con);
    var priceParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@price", SqlDbType.Decimal);
    priceParameter.Precision = 18;
    priceParameter.Scale = 2;
    priceParameter.Value = decimalValue;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```